# Where is the database setup form for WP install in MAMP?

Tags: local-installation

I'm following the instructions on ["Installing WordPress Locally on Your Mac With MAMP"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) and I'm on step 4. The problem I'm having is in this sentence:

> "Lastly, we've got to run WordPress' famous 5-minute install. Visit your local site (localhost:port or localhost:port/wordpress), and enter the following information into the database setup form:
>
> ```
>     Database Name: wordpresstest
>     User Name (database): root
>     Password (database): root
>     Database Host/server: localhost
>     Table Prefix: wp_
> ```

Ok, I have no idea what database setup form the instructions are referring to. I don't see where I'm supposed to find this form. Is it under some tab? Are they even still referring to the phpMyAdmin area?

It would be great if someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I figured out the problem by going to [this site.](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/develop-wordpress-locally-mamp/)

Forgot to include the actual files in the WP folder in htdocs. :\ D'oh!